# How to use Ext.data.writer.Json to create a model object with nameProperty applied

Tags: java, javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I have nameProperty set in the proxy of my store like this :
Code:

```
writer : {
        type : 'json',
        nameProperty : 'mapping',
        root : 'PerVO'
    }
```

And in my model , the mapping like this:

```
        {
            name : 'modules',
            mapping : 'modules.collection',
            defaultValue: []
        },
```

This works fine when I call the CRUD operations on the store. Now I want to get the data in the format being sent to the server for other operations. The problem is that when I get the record from the store , the mapping is lost. So how can I useExt.data.writer.Json or some other api to generate the data EXACTLY as it would be generated while being sent to the server with mapping applied :

This is what the store sends for save (I need the data like this. Note : Difference is 'collection:')

```
    "modules": {
        "collection": {
            "isActive": 1,
            "metadata": {
                "actionCodes": "",
                "memos": ""
            },
            "moduleCode": "OM",
            "moduleId": 250,
            "moduleName": "Org Management",
            "success": false,
            "viewId": 0
        }
    },
```

This is what i get from the store when the record is looked up:

```
                 "modules": {
                    "isActive": 1,
                    "metadata": {
                        "actionCodes": "",
                        "memos": ""
                    },
                    "moduleCode": "OM",
                    "moduleId": 250,
                    "moduleName": "Org Management",
                    "success": false,
                    "viewId": 0
                },
```

I need to get the data as sent by the store to server.
Thanks
Nohsib

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the name in the mapping to the following

```
{
   name : 'collection',
   mapping : 'modules.collection',
   defaultValue: []
}
```

The `name` config is the name that is used within the `model`. If you look at the `data` property of a `model` object, the `name` used in the mapping is used to store the value in the `model`. The `name` is same name that we use while retrieving data from a `model` object too. Ex. `model.get(name);`

From the [api](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Field-cfg-name).

> The name by which the field is referenced within the Model